# Heroku not obeying scripts.start command

Tags: node.js, heroku

I've just tried to deploy the latest version of my Node app to Heroku.  I was using `let` from the ES2015 spec

It kept failing as during the start-up Heroku ran:

`` 2015-09-04T21:36:09.334796+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `node app.js` ``

And then crashed when it hit the `let` or `const` keywords (I had "use strict" set)

However, my package.json was specifying the --harmony flag

`"scripts": {
    "start": "node --harmony app.js",
    "test": "mocha test"
  },`

Nine times out of 10, this is user error.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it says it's starting with `node app.js` then that's the exact command it's using. Keep in mind that the precedence order for starting the app is:

1. Procfile and
2. scripts.start if a Procfile doesn't exist

Do you perhaps have a `Procfile` in the app directory with something like `web: node app.js` in it?

*disclosure: I'm the Node.js platform owner at Heroku*

Comment: Perfect answer.  I'd interpreted the docs to mean that the Procfile was superseded by the Package.json, but re-reading them it is clear that you simply don't *need* a Procfile if you're got scripts.start set.  Thank you.